# How do I inject NavigationManager in a Quartz.NET job?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, quartz.net

I have a Blazor server-side application that uses Quartz.NET to run a scheduled job. The job merely calls an injected helper class...

```cs
  public class DownloadEmailsJob : IJob {
    private readonly EmailDownloadHelper _edh;

    public DownloadEmailsJob(EmailDownloadHelper edh) =>
      _edh = edh;

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) =>
      await _edh.DownloadEmails();
  }
```

`EmailDownloadHelper` uses injection to get various services, such as the `DbContext`, etc. That part is all working fine.

I now have a need to call a SignalR hub method from inside the helper class. Following the code [in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server), in order to create the hub connection, I need to do something like this...

```cs
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(EmailNotifierHub.Endpoint))
  .Build();
```

...where `EmailNotifierHub` contains the following line...

```cs
public const string Endpoint = "/EmailHub";
```

This means that I need an instance of `NavigationManager` in my job. I tried injecting it in the constructor (as I do with the other dependencies in this class), but when it tries to create the hub connection, I get an exception...

> System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll
> 'RemoteNavigationManager' has not been initialized

The instance of `NavigationManager` is injected fine, meaning it's not null, and the exception only comes when it tries to call `ToAbsoluteUri`

I've done this sort of thing before in injected classes, but not in a Quartz.NET job, which is where I suspect the problem lies.

Anyone able to explain what's going wrong, and how I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that `NavigationManager` does not work properly outside a `Circuit`, and Quartz is (presumably) set up once for the application. The DI, therefore, does not have a scope in which it can provide a `NavigationManager`.

In similar situations, I usually resign to setting the base url of the site in appsettings.json, and use that to construct the absolute urls I need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I ended up doing. Shame, it would have been nice.